# material chips with radio buttons

Tags: angular, angular-material-6

I'm currently working on angular material. Facing a situation where I want to make material chips with radio buttons.

I want to get data something like [{text: 'abc', code: 0 }, ...]

What I tried till now is below. Do let me know if required more information.

.ts file

```js
myForm: FormGroup;
  arr: FormArray;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
      arr: this._fb.array([this.createItem()])
    })
  }

  createItem() {
    return this._fb.group({
      name: [null],
      code: [null]
    })
  }

  getValue() {
    console.log(this.myForm.get('arr').value)
  }

  add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;

    if ((value || '').trim()) {
      this.arr = this.myForm.get('arr') as FormArray;
      this.arr.push(this.createItem());
    }

    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }
  }
```

HTML

```html
<div>
  <form action="" [formGroup]="myForm">
    <mat-form-field class="example-chip-list" formArrayName="arr" *ngFor="let a of myForm.get('arr').controls; let i = index">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <mat-chip-list #chipList>
    <mat-chip [selectable]="selectable"
             [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(a)">
      {{a.get('name').value}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
      <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" formControlName="code">
        <mat-radio-button value="1">1</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="2">2</mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
    </mat-chip>
    <input formControlName="name"
           [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
           [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
           [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
           (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
  </mat-chip-list>
      </div>
</mat-form-field>
  </form>
  <button (click)="getValue()">submit</button>
</div>
```

Unable to get the desired result. Not able to find the way of going forward. Thanks in advance

Comment: you want a radio input inside of a chip?

Comment: yes, radio buttons inside each chip entered and data like given example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is "unconventional" to say the least, but the issue is that your name control actually needs to exist outside of your form array since it doesn't belong to every item in the array:

```
  <form action="" [formGroup]="myForm">
    <mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
      <mat-chip-list #chipList>
        <ng-container formArrayName="arr"> <!-- array here -->
          <mat-chip  *ngFor="let a of arr.controls; let i = index"
             [selectable]="selectable"
             [removable]="removable" 
             (removed)="remove(a)" 
             [formGroupName]="i"> <!-- ngFor and group here -->
            {{a.get('text').value}} <!-- show text control value -->
            <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
            <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" formControlName="code">
              <mat-radio-button value="1">1</mat-radio-button>
              <mat-radio-button value="2">2</mat-radio-button>
            </mat-radio-group>
          </mat-chip>
        </ng-container>
        <input formControlName="name"
          [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
          [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
          [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
          (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
      </mat-chip-list>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
```

then modify your component:

```
  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
      name: [''], // add name control here
      arr: this._fb.array([]) // init empty
    })
  }


  createItem(text) { // change this to have text ctrl and accept value
    return this._fb.group({
      text: [text], // set value
      code: [null] // optional to add default val here
    })
  }

  get arr() { // handy helper
    return this.myForm.get('arr') as FormArray;
  }

  add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const value = event.value;

    if ((value || '').trim()) {
      this.arr.push(this.createItem(value)); // feed in the value
    }

    // Reset the input value for the reactive form
    this.myForm.get('name').setValue('');
  }
```

here's what your remove function would look like:

```
remove(i: index) {
  this.arr.removeAt(i);
}
```

and in your template, call it with the index:

```
(removed)="remove(i)"
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. One last question though, how can i remove the chip as splice doesn't work on formArray.

Comment: no it doesn't. but form arrays do have a removeAt method which accepts an index

Comment: added what the remove function should look like